# How to get all props from a component that is being passed as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this component called **SpecialComp** that is being passed as a prop to **MyComp** . My question is how to pass all of the props from **SpecialComp** (color, size, weight) to MyComp so then I can override the attributes set in MyComp? In other words how can I have access to SpecialComp’s props inside of MyComp?

```
<MyComp customcomp ={<SpecialComp color=‘green’ size=‘20’ weight=‘bold’/>} />

export const MyComp = ({customcomp}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {React.cloneElement(customcomp, {color: ‘red’})}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: use redux or some global variables?

Comment: this app doesn’t use Redux and will not be using it either

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

Comment: Doesn't `customcomp.props` work ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access the props by calling **`customcomp.props`**.

```
<MyComp
    customcomp={<SpecialComp color="green" size="20px" weight="bold" />}
  />
```

---

```
const MyComp = ({ customcomp }) => {

  console.log(customcomp.props);
  //Prints: {color: "green", size: "20px", weight: "bold"}

  return <div>{React.cloneElement(customcomp, { color: "red" })}</div>;
};

export default MyComp;
```

codeSandbox for this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-shadow-4fdp59?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make use of any state management solution. Then you can consider [lifting the state (prop) up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). See code examples below:

```
import React from "react";

export const App = () => {
  const [specialProps, setSpecialProps] = useState({
    color: "green",
    size: "20",
    weight: "bold",
  }); // make the properties as state

  return (
    <MyComp
      customComponentStyles={specialProps} // you can pass it here
      customComponent={
        <SpecialComp
          color={specialProps.color} // you can pass it here too
          size={specialProps.size}
          weight={specialProps.weight}
        />
      }
    />
  );
};

export const MyComp = ({ customComponentStyles, customComponent }) => { // access the same prop here as well
  return <div>{React.cloneElement(customcomp, { color: "red" })}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Can you explain your answer?
Refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidline to improve your contribution.

Comment: The code, I believe, is self-explanatory with comments. Please let me know if this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<MyComp customcomp ={<SpecialComp color=‘green’ size=‘20’ weight=‘bold’/>} />

export const MyComp = ({customcomp}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {React.cloneElement(customcomp, {...customcomp.props,color: ‘red’})}
    </div>
  );
}
```